# Integrate with Subscript: does this crash your kernel too?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, kernel

I encountered some strange behaviour running v10.0.1 on a Mac Pro, while working with `Integrate` and `Subscript`.  Starting from a fresh kernel:

```
SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldFirst]
```

Then, the following integral:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[Subscript[z, 1]^2 + Subscript[z, 2]^2]/E^((Subscript[z, 1]^2 
+ Subscript[z, 2]^2)/2), {Subscript[z, 2], -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

... causes my Mac Mma kernel to Quit. It just disappears ... no output ... and the kernel goes dead.

Does this happen on other platforms as well?

P.S. Plainly, a workaround is not to use subscript - but the issue is not how to find a workaround, but to check if this is a general problem.

---

Murray asks:

> Why do you want to set the `HoldFirst` attribute for `Subscript`?

The idea for this goes back many years to a suggestion made originally by Carl Woll (I believe). It's a nifty trick that allows one to work with symbols say $t$ and $t_1$, mostly without conflict, at the same time (well, that's the plan).

For example, if your Mma session is activated with:

```
 SetAttributes[Subscript, HoldFirst]
```

and someone enters:

```
t = 34;
```

... and you then evaluate $t_1$:

```
 Subscript[t,1]
```

... Mma returns $t_1$ ... not the more wacky $34_1$. In essence, it offers most of the benefits  of the old Symbolize package (which I never liked), while still retaining the flexibility to enter things like:

```
Table[ Subscript[t, i], {i, 5}]
```

It is part of my everyday Mma routine, and also a default setting in the *mathStatica* package.

Comment: Without `etAttributes[Subscript, HoldFirst]`, evaluating that `Integrate` expression under *Mathematica* 10.0.1 on my iMac almost immediate gives an answer, as a `ConditionalExpression`, involving `HypergeometricU` function under the condition that the real part of $z_i^2 > 0$. Why do you want to set the `HoldFirst` attribute for `Subscript`?

Comment: It's a small bug coupled with some very dangerous programming practice. As I'm sure I've mentioned to you in past. As for how general is the problem, it can show up anywhere Mathematica needs to make an internal "polynomial" from something involving a rational power and a base with the held subscript. Which is to say, it can arise in many, many ways.